# How to add tabs in the action bar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I added some tab buttons in the action bar of my app. But I don't know how to add the coding to the each tab button. I want to open a new layouts from each tab button. I can't find the ids for these buttons.(I'm a beginner for android) Thank you!

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));
}
```

I got tabs by using this this code in the onCreate method.

Comment: Try a library like actionbarsherlock it ll help you doing the job at first (then if you when to switch to android action bar you can anytime)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Creating Android Tab */

    Tab tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("My Tabs").setIcon(R.drawable.myfriends).setTabListener(tabListener);
    Tab tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionabar.addTab(tab);
    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener);                               
    actionabar.addTab(tab);       
    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("Tab3").setTabListener(tabListener);                               
    actionabar.addTab(tab);
```

Use switch case to shift to tabs

```
switch (position) {
case 0:
    tabLayout = R.layout.tab1;
    break;
case 1:
    tabLayout = R.layout.tab2;
    break;
case 2:
    tabLayout = R.layout.tab3;
    break;
}
```

Comment: what did you mean by position here??

Comment: Position is the tab number, if it is first tab its case 0 it will show the tab1 layout defined in your xml.